# BeautifulSoup [ ] contains no links

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So i'm trying to scrape links from this site: https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/

My program doesnt seem to find the links. I'm thinking it's a security measure and the site doesn't want people to retrieve the information(?).

Do i have to add an extra line to dig into the "li" tab perhaps?

Would be so so grateful if anyone helped me get past this problem.

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


result = requests.get("https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

urls = []
for h2_tag in soup.find_all('li'):
    a_tag = h2_tag.find('a')
    urls.append(a_tag.attrs['href'])

print(urls)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Actually the webpage is rendered via `JavaScript`

Here's `Selenium` approach:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get('https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/')
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'text'}):
    item = item.get("href")
    print(f"https://spotlightstockmarket.com{item}")

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=54904&publisher=370
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=54902&publisher=370
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=54903&publisher=370
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=54901&publisher=370
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=54900&publisher=370
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=54899&publisher=370
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=54898&publisher=370
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=54897&publisher=370
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=54896&publisher=370
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=54894&publisher=370
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=26715&publisher=371
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=26714&publisher=371
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=26713&publisher=371
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=1880&publisher=372
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=1879&publisher=372
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=26712&publisher=371
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=26711&publisher=371
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=26710&publisher=371
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=26709&publisher=371
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=26708&publisher=371
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=54808&publisher=369
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=54809&publisher=369
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=54790&publisher=369
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=54776&publisher=369
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=54747&publisher=369
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=54741&publisher=369
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=54721&publisher=369
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=54720&publisher=369
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=54707&publisher=369
https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/nyhets-artikel/?id=54706&publisher=369
```

Regarding `li` it's not rendered with `JavaScript` so you can use:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


r = requests.get(
    "https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

urls = set()
for item in soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'li' and not tag.attrs):
    for href in item.findAll("a"):
        href = href.get("href")
        if href:
            href = f"https://spotlightstockmarket.com{href}"
        urls.add(href)

print(urls)
```

Output:

```
{'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/om-spotlight/kontakt', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/rapportkalender', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/redan-noterad/next', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/bli-delaegare', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/om-spotlight', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/redan-noterad/regelverk', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/medlemmar/medlemslista', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/redan-noterad/i-fokus', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/redan-noterad/information-foer-att-uppraetta-din-ir-sida', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/redan-noterad/kapitalanskaffning', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/kurser', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/bolagshaendelser', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/vaara-bolag', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/redan-noterad/investor-relations', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/filmer', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/om-spotlight/koncerninformation', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/en/market-overview/news', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/bli-delaegare/hur-blir-jag-delaegare', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/om-spotlight/oeppettider', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/bli-noterad/go-public', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/redan-noterad/disciplinnaemnden', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/noteringar', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/medlemmar/regelverk-och-prislista', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/redan-noterad', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/bli-noterad/vaart-erbjudande', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/redan-noterad/vaart-erbjudande', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/analyser', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/bli-noterad', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/bli-noterad/hur-gaar-en-notering-till', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/redan-noterad/vaegledning', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/redan-noterad/boka-utbildning', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/bli-noterad/spotlight-stories', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/om-spotlight/pressbilder', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/bli-noterad/varfoer-bli-noterad', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/medlemmar', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/dk/market-overview/nyheder', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/spotlight-index', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/bli-delaegare/varfoer-bli-delaegare', 'https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/emissioner'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Data is retrieved dynamically from a javascript object when javascript runs in the browser. You can regex out the urls simply as follows as that object is present in the response.text. This avoids the overhead of using a browser.

```
import requests, re

p = re.compile(r'"url": "(.*?)",')
r = requests.get('https://spotlightstockmarket.com/sv/market-overview/nyheter/')
links = ['https://spotlightstockmarket.com' + link for link in p.findall(r.text)]
print(links)
```

Regex:

[image]